# How to run function through ternary operator in Angular template?

Tags: angular

I have tried something like this:

```
 <input *ngIf="this.checkAll ? (this.undefinedDocuments$ | async)?.length > 0 : (!this.undefinedDocuments$ | async)?.length > 0" [checked]="this.checkAll" (click)="this.checkAll ? this.handleCheckAllClick() : this.handleUncheckAllClick()" class="styled-checkbox" id="checkAllCheckbox" type="checkbox">
```

But it won't work. I basically want this to work as a "Check All" & "Uncheck All" input.

Comment: Consider doing it programmatically. This helps to reduce the time taken for others to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check boolean on `(click)` event. You can make one common function in `component.ts`, and call that function on `(click)` event, and check `this.checkAll` in that function and call `this.handleCheckAllClick()` and `this.handleUnCheckAllClick()` from there accordingly.

**HTML:**

```
<input *ngIf="this.checkAll ? (this.undefinedDocuments$ | async)?.length > 0 : (!this.undefinedDocuments$ | async)?.length > 0" [checked]="this.checkAll" (click)="commonFuncion()" class="styled-checkbox" id="checkAllCheckbox" type="checkbox">
```

**Component:**

```
commonFunction() {
    if(this.checkAll) { this.handleCheckAllClick() } 
    else { this.handleUnCheckAllClick() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the functions you are calling on click.

When `checkAll` is `true` call `this.handleUncheckAllClick()` and when it is `false` call `this.handleCheckAllClick()`

```
<input *ngIf="this.checkAll ? (this.undefinedDocuments$ | async)?.length > 0 : (!this.undefinedDocuments$ | async)?.length > 0" [checked]="this.checkAll" (click)="this.checkAll ? this.handleUncheckAllClick() : this.handleCheckAllClick()" class="styled-checkbox" id="checkAllCheckbox" type="checkbox">
```

Initialize checkAll property as `false`

```
checkAll: boolean = false;
```